# How to use offline style definitions or map tiles in MapBox iOS/Android SDK?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, mapbox

I want to make offline map applications using mapbox iOS/Android SDK.

But, I load style from local filesystem, like below: (Sorry, I'm Xamarin user, so write in c#)

```
var bundlePath = NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath; 
var filePath = Path.Combine(bundlePath, "gsimaps.json"); 
var styleURL = NSUrl.CreateFileUrl (filePath, null);
var mapView = new MapView (Bounds, styleURL);
```

Then error shows:

> [ERROR] {Map}[Setup]: loading style failed: response class is not NSHTTPURLResponse

Are there any way to load styles from local data?
From file, from DB, from memory, any means are OK, I want to know the way to use local data.

And also, are there any ways to use local raster tile in MapBox SDK? (From file, DB, or memory..)

Answer (score 1):

In Android,

First, declare a `map_style.json` inside **assets** folder

Then in Java code

```
mapView.setStyleUrl("asset://map_style.json");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at my github project [**(Tiles for Android/iOS/UWP)**](https://github.com/Emixam23/XamarinByEmixam23/tree/master/Detailed%20Part/Controls/Map/MapTileProject/MapTileProject) but I have a problem with the updating of these tiles -> [**Double update for tiles..**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38536350/edit)

Answer (score 0):

MapBox have a plan to implement local interface:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/7471